# Black screen on boot

Tags: 12.04, 11.10, startup, flicker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I've just installed Ubuntu and i can't access the desktop because the screen sometimes flickers and sometimes it gets black.

Here are my PC specifications:

- Gigabyte z68a-d3-b3 motherboard
- 4  Gb Kingston RAM
- AMD radeon HD 6850 graphics card
- Intel i5 3.4 GHz processor,