# Problem while installing ubuntu with ATI Radeon 6670 HD

Tags: ati

i have recorded what exactly happens with me

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fA-pjFx-UU

*P.S, everything worked fine with ATI Radeon 4670 HD, this issue happened when i changed my VGA to 6670, and i got this issue with any version of ubuntu*

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is your Graphics card ?

Comment: ATI Radeon 6670 HD

Comment: Have you Installed the proprietary drivers? if so, which ones? , which Ubuntu version? What have you tried? don't let information out of your question.

Comment: no i haven't installed any proprietary driver (how to do?)
and i tried 11.10 and 12.4 versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Muhammad

You could try editing the install options and change "quiet splash" with nomodeset, this should inhibit the installer loading a graphics driver which causes your problem. I'm not sure the details but I had to use this once when I installed ubuntu and you can find details in forums. It appears to be a bit of a dark art!

There is an alternative installer which I read is text base, Ive never used it perhaps someone can confirm this?

I found a similar problem here for boot but I assume it's driver problem and it should work too.

[Black screen on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110315/ubuntu-11-10-and-12-04-blackscreen-on-boot)

Comment: nomodeset worked for me and i installed 12.4 but i have same issue when i try to open my ubuntu, what should i do after i the installation?

Comment: i installed ATI driver and everything worked fine :)